# How to group and index a pandas DataFrame to get a desired box plot

Tags: python, pandas

I have data that looks like:

```
Region = [random.choice([1,2,3,4,5]) for x in range(100)]
Gender = [random.choice(['Male', 'Female']) for x in range(100)]
Balance = [random.random()*1000 for x in range(100)]
df = pd.DataFrame({'Region':Region, 'Gender':Gender, 'Balance':Balance})
```

I want to get a multi-indexed DataFrame with index (Region, Gender) so that I can call `df.plot.box(vert=False)` and get something like this (Produced in R) out.

[image: Multi-indexed box plot]

This seems like it should be simple but I can't seem to get the right reshaping / indexing.

Comment: Where you do `Gender = [random.choice('Male', 'Female') for x in range(100)]` you have to do `Gender = [random.choice(['Male', 'Female']) for x in range(100)]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
np.random.seed(23)
Region = np.random.choice([1,2,3,4,5], size=100)
Gender = np.random.choice(['Male', 'Female'], size=100)
Balance = np.random.rand(100)*1000 
df = pd.DataFrame({'Region':Region, 'Gender':Gender, 'Balance':Balance})
print (df.head())
      Balance  Gender  Region
0  384.491355  Female       4
1  328.787350  Female       1
2  529.003182    Male       2
3   96.884964  Female       1
4   23.379931    Male       5
```

I think need concatenate `Region` and `Gender` first, use [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for count each group for `pivot`:

```
idx = df['Region'].astype(str) + '.' + df['Gender']
cols = idx.groupby(idx).cumcount()
df1 = pd.pivot(index=cols, columns=idx, values=df['Balance'])
print (df1)

print (df1.head())

     1.Female      1.Male    2.Female      2.Male    3.Female      3.Male  \
0  328.787350  298.232904  888.262152  529.003182  959.644810  962.342645   
1   96.884964  780.852785  738.040024  760.956146  119.652522  601.118950   
2  910.707827  611.333680  116.517822  155.214746  140.653479  688.654958   
3   50.119030  205.932674  148.848025  794.379306  380.307363  194.257663   
4  263.554386  605.087006  953.241083  113.801236  778.912082  170.791317   

     4.Female      4.Male    5.Female      5.Male  
0  384.491355  122.347230  400.107360   23.379931  
1  190.038651  564.785449  330.269653  998.586681  
2  521.390446  757.714947  512.813561  185.192917  
3  566.314099  939.538858  480.686727   80.862220  
4  927.260017  175.496721  342.465179  287.932951  

df1.plot.box(vert=False)
```

[image: graph]

---

Old solutions:

It seems you need reshape by [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and aggregate `mean` or [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
a = df.groupby(['Gender','Region'])['Balance'].mean().unstack()
#alternatively
#a = df.pivot_table(index='Gender', columns='Region', values='Balance', aggfunc='mean')
print (a)
Region           1           2           3           4           5
Gender                                                            
Female  357.970914  679.143664  442.473514  498.600391  618.475656
Male    531.211030  462.071729  470.280364  623.540595  362.917609

a.plot.box(vert=False)


b = df.groupby(['Region','Gender'])['Balance'].mean().unstack()
print (b)
Gender      Female        Male
Region                        
1       357.970914  531.211030
2       679.143664  462.071729
3       442.473514  470.280364
4       498.600391  623.540595
5       618.475656  362.917609

b.plot.box(vert=False)
```

Comment: Nice work, thank you.  Could you explain `cols = idx.groupby(idx).cumcount()` a little?  A series grouped by itself to make the pivot index doesn't seem intuitive.  And what does the cumulative count call do here?

Comment: Hmmm, I try create solution without new columns, so  is same as df['idx'] = df['Region'].astype(str) + '.' + df['Gender'], then df['cols'] = df.groupby('idx').cumcount() and last df1 = df.pivot(index='cols', columns='idx', values='Balance')
print (df1). And idx.groupby(idx) is used if need cumcount with series. Good luck!